# Manually create/populate .NET Session object

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, caching

First a brief background. I am using .NET output caching and substitution controls to keep a few bits updated on each page refresh. The static methods that the substitution controls use require access to the Session object.  Unfortunately, the HttpContext session is null in those methods.

I'm not going to rewrite my app to use a different store than the Session. Session is perfect for everything I need except this one aspect.

Can I manually create or populate a session object or otherwise get at its data by some sort of black magic wizardry? The session cookie is still being set from the client to the server. The info has got to be there somewhere. How do I get at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is a "good" way to go...but you can very dodgily store a reference to the Session in a shared/static variable and access it then.

```
Public Class SessionHelper

    Public Shared TheSession As HttpSessionState

End Class
```

In your Session Start event (haven't figured out the best place to put it yet as the session isn't available in Application start as far as I am aware)

```
Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' Store a reference...only do this once etc etc
    If SessionHelper.TheSession Is Nothing Then
        SessionHelper.TheSession = HttpContext.Current.Session
    End If

End Sub
```

Then in your code you can just reference the helper

```
Dim someVariable as String = SessionHelper.TheSession.Item("ItemName")
```

A few things I'm not sure about this method:

- not sure if the session object is now not thread safe
- it doesn't seem quite right
- this example is extremely simple...

**Edit**
I verified this worked for me by adding something to the cache and seeing if the session was available in the Cache Remove Callback which Http.Context.Current is not available in.

**Edit 2**
Here's a screenshot of it correctly returning the value. So it must be working to some degree, but the fact that the SessionId is not set is kind of worrying...I know I've used this technique before to access the Cache object but the cache is the cache, where as the session does need something to identify each session...Here you go anyway:
[image]

Comment: This definitely seems hacky and I might regret doing it, but this works for me and I'm going to go for it. I changed it to store the Sessions in a `Dictionary<string, HttpSessionState>` where the key is the SessionID. That way, I'm a little more thread-safe.

Comment: This didnt work. Not really. I was able to reference the session but it didnt have any items. Were you able to access the items collection using your approach?

Comment: I will check...however, remember, you are not storing "each" session...just the session object as a whole...so you only need to store it once if that makes sense...

Comment: @Jeff, see edit...THinking I might just delete this answer because it's likely of no good...see what you think.

Comment: I actually got it to work. I'm not sure exactly what the issue was, but instead of saving the reference to the Session at Session Start, I saved it when I accessed it during `Page_Load` events or somewhere similar.

Comment: Apparently there are multiple instances of the Session hanging around because the references at Session Start were different from the references at Page.Load. Not quite sure ... but it works! So far it seems reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Session information is stored in the server's memory. You can, however, [configure ASP.NET to store the session information inside SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604).

Comment: Isnt there performance overhead to the database calls? I've seen articles about this before but have always shyed away.

Comment: @Jeff - Yes, it will definately slow down performance to a degree. Not a huge degree, but to some degree. If your application is speed sensitive, then this may not be the way to go. An alternative it read [this artice](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/sessiontool.aspx) which is a tool that will allow you to explore and view your session state.

Comment: @m4tt1mus - If the data is in a database, then you can see the session data just by using Query Analyzer to pull the data from table rows

Comment: You should probably include that in your answer, just switching to storing the session state in SQL isn't going to do anything to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

HttpContext.Current.Session should give you access to the current Session. The only time when this would not work is when there is no current HttpContext. As long as you have a reference to System.Web, it should work.

Comment: It doesnt work. `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null. Even Scott Guthrie is quoted as saying it isn't available in my situation.

Comment: It all depends on what stage of the Page pipeline your code is attempting to access Session. If the current handler implements either IRequiresSessionState or IReadOnlySessionState, then Session will be available.